# Use of <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I try to implement this script tag in my html code but don't know the use of 'bootstrap4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'
link. Can anyone explain what's the use of this????

Use of 'bootstrap-4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js' link in the script tag as src.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask here. Are you asking why Bootstrap has some JavaScript? This *is* covered by the introduction page on the documentation. Are you asking what the value you give to a `src` attribute for a script element means? Have you tried an HTML reference such as can be found on MDN?

Comment: Bootstrap 4.4.1 is very old. It isn't the latest version of the 4.x branch and Boostrap has moved onto the 5.x now. You should consider upgrading, especially if you are just introducing Bootstrap to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some bootstrap features require javascript. By placing this script, these features can be used.